# Clarity in proving pigeon hole principle

Tags: functions, proof-verification

I have seen quite a rigorous proof (below) and was wondering why you can **assume that n is minimal** and then contradict this fact. Surely proof by contradiction is just disproving the negation of the original statement, why is minimality of n involved?

Here it is:

Prove: Let $J_n$ = {1,2,...,n}. For m,n are elements of natural numbers inc. zero, then there is no injection $J_m$ -> $J_n$.

Proof:

Suppose for contradiction, that there is some injection f : $J_m$  -> $J_n$  (m>n) and choose n to be as small as possible.

Let f(m) = k where k is an element of $J_n$ , and let t : $J_n$  -> $J_n$  be a bijection that swaps k and n, and fixes everything else (identity map if k = n)

Then t o f : $J_m$  -> $J_n$  : m |-> n is an injection

Then we can restrict the domain and co-domain to get an injection:

f~ : $J_m$$_-$$_1$  -> $J_n$$_-$$_1$  thus contradiction, due to minimality of n.

(Apologies for incorrect formatting, t o f denotes t composed on f)

Comment: Also, is using "some" bijection that swaps k and n sufficient, or do I have to define a bijection which has this property (swaps k and n, but fixes everything else)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please have a look at this [helpful formatting tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This must be stated incorrectly.  Obviously there is an injection from $J_m$ to $J_n$ if $m\leq n$  $f(x)=x$ is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside this particular proof, let's look at the general idea of assuming some $n$ is minimal in a proof of this type.

In general then, you are trying to prove a particular result and are going to prove this by contradiction. In other words you are going to assume there is a counterexample.

If you are lucky, then your counterexample will involve some parameter $n$ which is a positive integer. Instead of looking at any counterexample, looking at a counterexample for which $n$ is least gives you added information - you can assume that for all smaller values of $n$ there are **no** counterexamples.

This often gives you useful results about your *minimal* counterexample. In the proof you give as an example there is a restriction to a smaller $n$.